# I am using NodeJs currently now Node has taken over my computer

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, node-modules

I installed Node and then started using it, it automatically integrated with my Code Runner in VS Code.
But later I wanted to use simple Import and Export ES6 modules instead of Node 'require' core modules but later on I realized that if I run my code without Node the code(And from that I mean a one-liner console.log() [Here check my image for the above problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYfe8.jpg) ) doesn't seem to be running, can someone help me out.
Do I need to delete Node in order to run the code simply or what?
Please help, I am really annoyed.

Comment: Are you sure you could be able to run the javascript script just from powershell, without any host? Never heard of that. Instead, just execute `node ./practice1.js`.

Comment: Isn't this just a case of choosing what application `.js` files are associated with? You're basically "running" the file directly, so Windows will have some application associated with that file type, that it will use to run your file. (This is assuming you don't want to use Node to run those files, and want to use whatever you were using before node.)

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems perfectly fine, you just need to run the code using the following command for explicitly telling console to run your code using nodeJS

```
node ./practice1.js
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to run the code with code runner?

To run code: use shortcut `Ctrl+Alt+N`. or press `F1` and then select/type `Run Code` , or right click the Text Editor and then click `Run Code` in editor context menu.